# Error in Android Volley Syntax

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
        sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, 
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "SUCCESS"+jsonObject.getString("success"),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           startActivity(new 
                           Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                            }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error"+jsonObject.getString("Error"),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                          ,  new Response.ErrorListener() {
                      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Object error)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                })
                {
                    @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError 
                {
              HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashMap.put("email",email.getText().toString());

              hashMap.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    } }
```

There is an error in the following part:

*stating misplaced token ','*

```
new Response.ErrorListener()
{
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Object error)
 }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please don't just dump a full class, but instead only the relevant code. Also, please describe exactly what your problem is (e.g. the error you get).

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: post your error completely @Akanksha

Comment: You've misplaced a bracket. If you [format](https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer) your code properly, it'll be obvious.

Comment: @EnamulHaque i am getting error in new Response.ErrorListener() { public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Object error) } as misplaced token ','

Comment: have sever ever get request and response to volley.

Answer (score 0):

```
      sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view){

         request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,  
             new Response.Listener<String>() {

             @Override
             public void onResponse(String response) {
                 try {
                     JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                     if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "SUCCESS"+jsonObject.getString("success"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new 
                    Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                     }else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Error"+jsonObject.getString("Error"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

             }
             ,  new Response.ErrorListener() {
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Object error)
                 {

                 }
             }
         })

         {
             @Override
 protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError 
         {
       HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                 hashMap.put("email",email.getText().toString());

       hashMap.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                 return hashMap;
         }

         };

    requestQueue.add(request);

     }
 });
```

Comment: You placed your requestQue.add(request) inside the getParams() method. Which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced brackets everywhere. Try the below code,

```
request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "SUCCESS" + jsonObject.getString("success"),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error" + jsonObject.getString("Error"),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                hashMap.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
```